# Illegal string offset 'handler' in PHP

Tags: string, offset

Please how can I correct this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'handler' in /home/***************/public_html/whois/phpwhois/whois.gtld.php on line 95
```

on the following code:

```
function parse($data, $query)
{
$this->Query = array();
$this->SUBVERSION = sprintf("%s-%s", $query["handler"], $this->HANDLER_VERSION);
$this->result = generic_parser_b($data["rawdata"], $this->REG_FIELDS, 'dmy');
```

Comment: OK. Please consider this solved. I found the solution on this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654076/warning-illegal-string-offset-handler-in-c-wamp-www-whois-whois-whois-gtld-p

However, if you have something to add to it, I will appreciate.

Thank You!

Comment: Its an old post. I do looked for the solution so, sharing my finding solution which is already made for this by the phpwhois in github [https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/commit/8d3c57316e7d971de7ccc4a0acf775f12e504b60](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/commit/8d3c57316e7d971de7ccc4a0acf775f12e504b60)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if $query is a string if it is then the code will not work. Make sure you pass $enquiry as an array or fire an exception.